# expectation of the weighted sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_{i}(\omega)\geq 0$, for $i=1,\dots,k$, and $Y(\omega)\geq 0$ be the random variables defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, F,P)$, such that $E[X_{i}] \leq E[Y]$ for every $i$. Next, let $A_{i}$ be disjoint elements of the sigma-algebra $F$ such that $\cup_{i}A_{i} = \Omega$.
Are the following statements correct:
$$
\sum_{i}^{k}E[X_{i}]P[A_{i}] \leq E[Y]
$$
and
$$
\sum_{i}^{k}E[X_{i}I\{A_{i}\}] \leq E[Y]
$$
?

Comment: So $A_i$ and $X_i$ are indexed by the same set?

Comment: I do not understand you...

Comment: There are $k$ many $A_i$?

Comment: yes. exactly. the number of $A_{i}$ is the same as the number of rv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sum_i P(A_i) = 1$ and $E(X_i) \leq E(Y)$,

$$\sum_i E(X_i)P(A_i) \leq \sum_i E(Y)P(A_i) = E(Y).$$

The second inequality is false. Let $\Omega = \{1,2\}$, $X_i(i) = 2$ and $X_i(j)=0$ if $i \neq j$, $i,j \in \{1,2\}$. Let $P(i) = 1/2$, $i \in \Omega$. Then, $E(X_i) = 1$, so if $Y = 1$, then $E(X_i) \leq E(Y)$. But with $A_i = \{i\}$,

$$E(X_1I_{A_1}) + E(X_2 I_{A_2}) = 1 + 1 = 2 > 1 = E(Y).$$